# Magento 2 inline edit date issues

Tags: grid, magento-2.1, date, uicomponent

In magento2 Inline Edit date issues while i edit the record it display current date instead of my date

[image]

[image]

My Ui component

```
<!-- Date Column -->
        <column name="date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date</item> 
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MMM dd, YYYY</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: I have the problem too, first click is right time, second click is current time. The console has the error `Error creating Date object from string.` in file `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js`,  I think problem is from here, but doesn't find a solution, maybe it is a magento UI Component bug.

Comment: I have same issue. Have got the solution?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, not got any solution till now

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding this in my custom layout file :

Answer (score 0):

@RutveeSojitra @Ankur Bhadania

**I have resolved this issue by adding this in my ui component file :**

```
  <column name="date" sortOrder="40">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Date</item>
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```